# How do I calculate one-way lift and two-way lift? Explain like I'm a high school sophomore

Tags: data-visualization

Let's suppose that I have two data sets, $A$ and $B$. Both data sets have one million rows and both data sets have a dependent variable $y$ and an independent variable $x$. So far so good. But data set $B$, unlike data set $A$, has an additional dependent variable $\dot x$. In every other way, except for the addition of the column $\dot x$, data set $B$ is identical to data set $A$.

Model $S$ attempts to predict $y$ using $x$ alone, producing the predicted value $y_{S}$ Model $T$ attempts to predict $y$ using both $x$ and $\dot x$, yielding $y_T$.

After applying these models, model $S$ produces data set $\hat A$, which consists of one million rows of tuples $(y, y_S, x)$, while model $T$ produces data set $\hat B$, which consists of one million rows of tuples $(y, y_T, x, \dot x)$.

1. How do I create the one way lift curve comparing the improvement in predictive performance of including the additional variable?
2. How do I create the two way lift curve comparing the improvement in performance of including the additional variable?
3. What does the word "lift" mean in this context anyway?

Comment: Second question: are $A$ and $B$ independent of one another, or is $B$ simply $A$ with an additional variable on each observation?

Comment: Third question: can you provide a link (or citation) to the statistical concept of "lift?" I am unfamiliar with it, and other readers may also be.

Comment: @Alexis (1) I swapped independent and dependent (2) the latter (3) I'm going to ask a friend to supply the definition of lift.